# Why am I getting different query plans for the same query (on master / replicated servers)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am running the same query on a master and replicated server.

The settings on both servers in the postgresql.conf are the same however the master / write server has 32GB of RAM and the replicated / read server has 16GB of RAM.

This is the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
    m.sale_date,b.branch_name,
    m.transaction_type,
    TRIM(both ' '  from UPPER(l.master_code)) as stockcode, 
    (l.selling_price * l.quantity) * (1 + l.tax_percentage /100) as selling_price,l.quantity 
FROM 
    transaction_master m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    transaction_line_items l ON m.guid = l.link_guid 
INNER JOIN 
    branch_details b ON m.branch_code = b.branch_code 
WHERE 
    m.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-12-22' AND '2015-12-22' 
AND 
    (m.transaction_type = 'POSSALE' OR m.transaction_type = 'POSCN' OR         m.transaction_type = 'POSREF') 
ORDER BY 
    sale_date DESC nulls LAST
```

On the write server the total time is 14 seconds:

```
Sort  (cost=1625242.60..1625417.63 rows=70012 width=50) (actual time=14732.852..14734.362 rows=72522 loops=1)
  Sort Key: m.sale_date
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 11496kB
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=90258.98..1619608.28 rows=70012 width=50) (actual time=11202.434..14710.938 rows=72522 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((l.link_guid)::text = (m.guid)::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on transaction_line_items l  (cost=0.00..1258955.88 rows=23879388 width=62) (actual time=0.050..6612.397 rows=25147461 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=89903.39..89903.39 rows=28447 width=62) (actual time=46.941..46.941 rows=42504 loops=1)
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3948kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=4088.79..89903.39 rows=28447 width=62) (actual time=12.460..37.283 rows=42504 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((m.branch_code)::text = (b.branch_code)::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction_master m  (cost=4057.12..89480.57 rows=28447 width=52) (actual time=12.240..21.802 rows=42504 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSSALE'::text)) OR ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSCN'::text)) OR ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSREF'::text)))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1095
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=4057.12..4057.12 rows=29508 width=0) (actual time=12.112..12.112 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=28130 width=0) (actual time=6.013..6.013 rows=40615 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSSALE'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3.010..3.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                                  Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSCN'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=1378 width=0) (actual time=3.087..3.087 rows=1889 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSREF'::text))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=25.19..25.19 rows=519 width=18) (actual time=0.208..0.208 rows=519 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 26kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on branch_details b  (cost=0.00..25.19 rows=519 width=18) (actual time=0.006..0.119 rows=519 loops=1)
Planning time: 2.205 ms
Execution time: 14737.148 ms
```

The result from the replicated / read server takes 111 seconds:

```
Sort  (cost=3792870.57..3793045.60 rows=70012 width=50) (actual time=111432.945..111436.554 rows=72522 loops=1)
  Sort Key: m.sale_date
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 11496kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=95177.21..3787236.25 rows=70012 width=50) (actual time=62904.693..111410.002 rows=72522 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((m.branch_code)::text = (b.branch_code)::text)
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=95052.11..3778797.22 rows=70012 width=40) (actual time=62894.976..111265.547 rows=72522 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((l.link_guid)::text = (m.guid)::text)
              ->  Seq Scan on transaction_line_items l  (cost=0.00..3408100.80 rows=23879388 width=62) (actual time=0.010..96694.745 rows=25147447 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=92136.29..92136.29 rows=28447 width=52) (actual time=76.786..76.786 rows=42504 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3527kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction_master m  (cost=4057.12..92136.29 rows=28447 width=52) (actual time=28.078..59.330 rows=42504 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSSALE'::text)) OR ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSCN'::text)) OR ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSREF'::text)))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=1095
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=4057.12..4057.12 rows=29508 width=0) (actual time=27.824..27.824 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=28130 width=0) (actual time=14.828..14.828 rows=40615 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSSALE'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=6.552..6.552 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSCN'::text))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tm_datebranchtype  (cost=0.00..1345.26 rows=1378 width=0) (actual time=6.439..6.439 rows=1889 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((sale_date >= '2015-12-22'::date) AND (sale_date <= '2015-12-22'::date) AND ((transaction_type)::text = 'POSREF'::text))
        ->  Hash  (cost=71.90..71.90 rows=519 width=18) (actual time=0.457..0.457 rows=519 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 26kB
              ->  Seq Scan on branch_details b  (cost=0.00..71.90 rows=519 width=18) (actual time=0.009..0.259 rows=519 loops=1)
Planning time: 4.147 ms
Execution time: 111441.566 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting some help on the #postgresql IRC channel, I found out that the reason for the difference was that the setting for the cpu_tuple_cost was different on the 2 servers.

Once I changed the setting and reloaded the conf file, the query plan was the same on both servers.

Comment: What did you change it from? What did you change it to?

Comment: The default is set at 0.01, I had the updated one set at 0.1, once I changed back to the default the query plan was the same on both servers. However, the query ran much slower on the read due to there being less RAM on the server. (I'm assuming the RAM)